# What would be the fastest way to parse a Json String to a multidimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++, json, multidimensional-array, jsoncpp

I am currently using the JsonCPP library but it is proving be a bit slow for my needs. Appreciate your thoughts on this!

```
            json_response = response.extract_json().get();
            auto json = json_response.serialize();
            std::string res(json.begin(), json.end());
            //String to array
            auto arrayJson = json_response.at(U("loans")).as_array();
```

Comment: what's the use for `std::string res(json.begin(), json.end());` ?

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, Thanks for your reply. I use that later in the code for logging. It is just a widestring to string conversion..

Comment: Are you looking for a faster library? Or looking for a faster way to do it yourself?

Comment: Thanks. A faster library for the moment!